# The room, the table, and the chainsaw

Tags: wordplay

You're in a sealed room with no doors, vents, or windows. All that is in the room is a chainsaw, which has a full gas tank on it, and a table. How do you get out?

Comment: Saw a hole in the wall....

Comment: The walls are made of obsidian, and are too thick for you to cut through. BUT You're on the right track though ;)

Comment: If the room only contains a chainsaw and a table, which one are you?

Comment: @noedne he/she is the **tank**.

Comment: Guys, you aren't Cave Johnson.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You

> Saw the table in half, then the two halves make a (w)hole, then you escape through the hole.

Answer (score 6):

Forget the chainsaw and the table. You:

> get in the tank, start the engine and force your way through the wall.

Comment: No tank, sorry.

Comment: @CStafford-14 What do you mean 'no tank'? It's in the puzzle ;)

Comment: Where did I mention a tank?

Comment: Oh, it's a gas tank

Comment: @CStafford-14 A tank that runs on gas?

Comment: No, by "Tank" I mean container, so it's literally storage for the gas.

Comment: Wrong kind of tank

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility that doesn’t require anything other than yourself:

> Run laps around the room until you wear yourself *out.* Once that happens, you are *out,* so you’ve escaped the room.

Comment: Ha! That's a brilliant way of doing it.